# Switch rendering engine depending on render layer?

Tags: rendering

Can I somehow link the choice of render engine to the render layer?

I want to composite cycles and freestyle.
The render layers which I use in the compositor as inputs should 'know' which render engine they are supposed to use.  Maybe there is some python renderlayer-initialization-hook which I can leverage?

I do not like the workaround of creating three scenes, as maintenance overhead does not scale well. (or I'm doing it wrong?)

Answer (score 2):

You should use different scenes for each renderer. On the top toolbar next to where you select your render engine you can find to the left the scenes. Add a new scene and switch to the appropriate render engine.

**1.**

Rename the current scene to the render engine's name

**2.**

Create a *Link Object Data* copy of the current scene

[image]

**3.**

Rename it the other render engine and selected the render engine from the drop down to the right.

[image]

Comment: Like I wrote, the multiple-scenes workaround has the problem that e.g. new objects do not show up in both scenes, so one has to re-duplicate the scenes when one makes changes.  I would like to know if there is a better method?

Comment: This is a good question. THe method I posted is what I always do. Its not ideal but its what blender has to offer.